# The controller with the name is not registered error in UI Bootstrap Modal

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am not able to work out with controller that belongs to separate file in UIBootstrap modal functionality. However when I call the same piece of controller in same file then the functionality works perfectly.

Below the piece of code:-

**Test.html**

```
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>   
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>    
    <script src="../Scripts/AngularControllers/Test.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">       
        <button type="button"  ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>       
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Test1.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title> 
</head>
<body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">        
        <h1>Modal Body</h1>
        Please Provide Duration
        <select ng-model="selectedDays" ng-options="x for x in Days"></select>

</body>
</html>
```

**Test.js** *(This works fine as both the controller present in same file)*

```
 var myApp =  angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    myApp.controller('ModalDemoCtrl',['$scope','$uibModal', function ($scope, $uibModal) {


        $scope.open = function (size, parentSelector) {       
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({            
                templateUrl: 'Test1.html',
                controller: 'ModalDemoCtrl1',
            });

        };


    }])
    .controller('ModalDemoCtrl1', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
        $scope.Days = ["Days", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];   

    }])
```

When I want to separate the bottom controller in another file and try to attach with Test1.html as below then I get the below error:-

> The controller with the name 'ModalDemoCtrl1' is not registered.

**Test.js** *(Modified)*

```
var myApp = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    myApp.controller('ModalDemoCtrl',['$scope','$uibModal', function ($scope, $uibModal) {


        $scope.open = function (size, parentSelector) {       
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({            
                templateUrl: 'Test1.html',
                controller: 'ModalDemoCtrl1',
            });

        };    
    }])
```

**Test 1.html** *(Modified)*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />   

    <script src="../Scripts/AngularControllers/Test1.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
    <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl1">        
        <h1>Modal Body</h1>
        Please Provide Duration
        <select ng-model="selectedDays" ng-options="x for x in Days"></select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Test1.js** *(New File Added)*

```
var myApp = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo');
myApp.controller('ModalDemoCtrl1', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
    $scope.Days = ["Days", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
}])
```

I want to place the code in the separate controller file like in Test1.js. Please let me know how to remove the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a working copy that should work for you**.

Here is the project folder structure :

[image]

**Pages/Test.html**

```
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>   
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>    
    <script src="../Scripts/App.module.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/AngularControllers/Test.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/AngularControllers/Test1.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">       
        <button type="button"  ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>       
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Pages/Test1.html**

```
<div>        
    <h1>Modal Body</h1>
    Please Provide Duration
    <select ng-model="selectedDays" ng-options="x for x in Days"></select>
</div>
```

Note that you no longer need <html> and <body> tags in **Test1.html** file

**Scripts/App.module.js**

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

this statement must be used once only in your application

**Scripts/AngularControllers/Test.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo');

myApp.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ['$scope','$uibModal', function ($scope, $uibModal) {
    $scope.open = function (size, parentSelector) {       
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({            
            templateUrl: 'test1.html',
            controller: 'ModalDemoCtrl1',
        });
    };
}]);
```

**Scripts/AngularControllers/Test1.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo');

myApp.controller('ModalDemoCtrl1', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
    $scope.Days = ["Days", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
}]);
```

I hope that helps. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks a ton for explaining me the answer in detail. Your working copy was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap'])...
```

twice results in redefining a module. The first copy of a module where a controller was registered is replaced.

For subsequent module uses module getter should be used instead:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo')...
```

Or even better, a submodule per each file. This eliminates potential race condition that can occur when using module getters.

Comment: I have changed the code of Test.js now and tried it. Please take a look above. That didn't seem to work. Is there anything that I didn't understand or I missed it? Please let me know

Comment: You shouldn't do `angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap'])` more than once. This piece of code should occur only once in your JS files. Ok, the module was defined 4 times previously, and now this is done 2 times. This results in redefining it any way.

Comment: I have modified Test1.js to get the module ''ui.bootstrap.demo" only instead of initializing everytime. While doing so I also thought that it should work but sorry to say that it didn't work.. Is there anything that need to be changed in html files? It will be great if you please provide me working copy of this example.

Comment: I don't really follow what happens in your html files. You're loading test1.js on one page and not loading on another, aren't you? Of course, this will make a controller not registered. Both test.js and test1.js should be loaded, exactly in this order. A working copy is the responsibility of the asker, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please, provide a plunk/fiddle that can replicate the problem, so it could be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring the **ui.bootstrap.demo** module twice

in test.js file just remove the first line which is an extra declaration:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Comment: I have modified Test.js code now. Please take a look above. I have tried this but got no luck. Anything extra that I need to be done.

Comment: change again the test.js file first line to:
var myApp = angular.module('ui.bootsrap.demo');

Comment: If I remove ['ui.bootstrap'] from first line of test.js then the line willl be like below:-     var myApp = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo',[]);              .This result in following error :- "Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- ModalDemoCtrl". Am I missing anything?