# Gulp + Angular: (Error) The controller with the name 'foo' is not registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I don't know why the reason when I did the refactoring of my gulpfile, my project starts with this error "The controller with the name 'footerController' is not registered.".

When I open my scripts.js I found this controller there, and don't have any problem with the file (at least I don't think).

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```js
'use strict';

// *************************************
//
//   Gulpfile
//
// *************************************
//
// Available tasks:
//   `gulp`
//   `gulp build:html`
//   `gulp compile:sass`
//   `gulp build:styles`
//   `gulp build:images`
//   `gulp build:favicons`
//   `gulp build:vendors`
//   `gulp build:scripts`
//   `gulp build:fonts`
//   `gulp build:gzip`
//
// *************************************
// -------------------------------------
//   Modules
// -------------------------------------
//
// gulp              : The streaming build system
// gulp-autoprefixer : Prefix CSS
// gulp-concat       : Concatenate files
// gulp-csscss       : CSS redundancy analyzer *
// gulp-load-plugins : Automatically load Gulp plugins
// gulp-clean-css    : Minify CSS
// gulp-plumber      : Prevent pipe breaking from errors *
// gulp-sass         : Compile Sass
// gulp-uglify       : Minify JavaScript with UglifyJS
// gulp-watch        : Watch stream
// run-sequence      : Run a series of dependent Gulp tasks in order
//
// -------------------------------------

var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    plugin      = require('gulp-load-plugins')(),
    gulpif      = require('gulp-if'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    cssnano     = require('cssnano'),
    del         = require('del'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    spa         = require('browser-sync-spa'),
    streamqueue  = require('streamqueue'),
    templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
    karma       = require('karma').Server,
    wiredep     = require('wiredep').stream;

var config = {
    sourceDir: './src/',
    buildDir: './dist/',
    tempDir: './.tmp/',
    browserPort: 3000,
    UIPort: 3001,

    favicons: {
        src: 'src/assets/favicons/**/*',
        dest: 'dist/assets/favicons',
        temp: '.tmp/assets/favicons'
    },

    fonts: {
        src: 'src/assets/fonts/**/*',
        dest: 'dist/assets/fonts',
        temp: '.tmp/assets/fonts'
    },

    images: {
        src: 'src/assets/imgs/**/*',
        dest: 'dist/assets/imgs',
        temp: '.tmp/assets/imgs'
    },

    scripts: {
        src: 'src/**/*.js',
        files: 'src/**/*.js',
        dest: 'dist/js',
        temp: '.tmp/js'
    },

    styles: {
        src: 'src/styles/**/*.sass',
        compile: 'src/assets/css',
        dest: 'dist/assets/css',
        files: 'src/assets/sass/**/*.sass',
        temp: '.tmp/assets/css',
        options: {
            errLogToConsole: true,
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        }
    },

    templates: {
        src: [
            'src/partials/**/*.html',
            'src/pages/**/*.html',
            'src/components/**/*.html'
        ],
        files: 'src/**/*.html',
        index: 'src/index.html',
        dest: 'dist/js',
        temp: '.tmp/js'
    },

    gzip: {
        src: 'dist/**/*.{html,xml,json,css,js,js.map,css.map,svg}',
        dest: 'dist/',
        options: {}
    },

    css: [
        './bower_components/angular-carousel/dist/angular-carousel.css',
        './bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        './bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css',
        './bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css',
        './bower_components/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.css',
        './bower_components/angular-moment-picker/dist/angular-moment-picker.min.css',
        './bower_components/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css',
        './node_modules/@celulardireto/faq/dist/style.css',
        './node_modules/@celulardireto/search-cep/dist/style.css',
        './node_modules/@celulardireto/price/dist/style.css',
        './node_modules/@celulardireto/dados-pessoais/dist/style.css',
        './node_modules/@celulardireto/error-message/dist/style.css',
        'src/assets/css/style.css'
    ],

    files: [
        'src/app/app.module.js',
        'src/app/app.config.js',
        'src/app/app.router.js',
        'src/app/app.run.js',
        'src/services/**/*.js',
        'src/storages/**/*.js',
        'src/pages/**/*.js',
        'src/partials/**/*.js',
        'src/directives/**/*.js',
        'src/filters/**/*.js',
        'src/components/**/*.js'
    ],

    vendors: [
        './bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        './bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        './bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
        './bower_components/angular-carousel/dist/angular-carousel.js',
        './bower_components/spin.js/spin.js',
        './bower_components/angular-spinner/angular-spinner.js',
        './bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        './bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js',
        './bower_components/angular-input-masks/releases/angular-input-masks-standalone.js',
        './bower_components/ngLocale/angular-locale_pt-br.js',
        './bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
        './bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics.js',
        './bower_components/angulartics-google-analytics/lib/angulartics-ga.js',
        './bower_components/angulartics-google-tag-manager/lib/angulartics-google-tag-manager.js',
        './bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js',
        './bower_components/angular-slick/dist/slick.js',
        './bower_components/angular-slick-carousel/dist/angular-slick.min.js',
        './bower_components/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.tpls.js',
        './bower_components/linqjs/linq.js',
        './bower_components/moment/moment.js',
        './bower_components/moment/locale/pt-br.js',
        './bower_components/angular-moment-picker/dist/angular-moment-picker.min.js',
        './bower_components/lodash/lodash.js',
        './bower_components/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js',
        './bower_components/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js',
        './bower_components/ng-scrollbars/dist/scrollbars.min.js',
        './bower_components/ngInfiniteScroll/build/ng-infinite-scroll.js',
        './bower_components/qrcode.js/qrcode.js',
        './bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
        './bower_components/html2canvas/build/html2canvas.js',
        './node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
        './node_modules/@celulardireto/search-cep/dist/search-cep.component.js',
        './node_modules/@celulardireto/name-plans/dist/name-plans.component.js',
        './node_modules/@celulardireto/price/dist/price.component.js',
        './node_modules/@celulardireto/dados-pessoais/dist/dados.pessoais.component.js',
        './node_modules/@celulardireto/cd-directives/dist/cd.directives.js',
        './node_modules/@celulardireto/error-message/dist/error-message.component.js',
        './node_modules/angular-format-masks/dist/format-masks.component.js'
    ],
};

var reload = browserSync.reload;

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Del
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('del', function() {
    return del(global.isProd ? config.buildDir : config.tempDir);
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Compile: Sass
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('compile:sass', function() {
    gulp.src(config.styles.src)
        .pipe(plugin.sass(config.styles.options).on('error', plugin.sass.logError))
        .pipe(plugin.autoprefixer())
        .pipe(plugin.concat('styles.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.styles.compile))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Build: Favicon
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('build:favicons', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.favicons.src)
        .pipe(plugin.imagemin([], {
            verbose: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(global.isProd ? config.favicons.dest : config.favicons.temp));
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Build: Fonts
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('build:fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.fonts.src)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(global.isProd ? config.fonts.dest : config.fonts.temp));
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Build: Images
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('build:images', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.images.src)
        .pipe(plugin.imagemin([], {
            verbose: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(global.isProd ? config.images.dest : config.images.temp));
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Lint
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.scripts.files)
        .pipe(plugin.eslint())
        .pipe(plugin.eslint.format());
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Build: Styles
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('build:styles', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.css)
        // .pipe(plugin.useref())
        .pipe(plugin.sourcemaps.init())
        //.pipe(gulpif('*.css', plugin.postcss([require('postcss-flexibility'), cssnano()])))
        .pipe(plugin.autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(plugin.concat('styles.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulpif(global.isProd, plugin.cleanCss()))
        .pipe(plugin.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(global.isProd ? config.styles.dest : config.styles.temp))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: LoadingWA
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('loadingWA', function () {
    var componentLoadingPath = '/components/loading-locadoras/LOADING-LOCADORAS.hyperesources/';
    return gulp.src('src' + componentLoadingPath + '**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(global.isProd ? 'dist' + componentLoadingPath : '.tmp' + componentLoadingPath));
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Build: Scripts
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('build:scripts', ['lint'], function() {
    // return gulp.src(config.files)
    return streamqueue({ objectMode: true },
            gulp.src('./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'),
            gulp.src('./bower_components/angular/angular.js'),
            gulp.src('./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'),
            gulp.src('src/app/app.module.js'),
            gulp.src('src/app/app.config.js'),
            gulp.src('src/app/app.router.js'),
            gulp.src('src/app/app.run.js'),
            gulp.src('src/services/**/*.js'),
            gulp.src('src/storages/**/*.js'),
            gulp.src('src/pages/**/*.js'),
            gulp.src('src/partials/**/*.js'),
            gulp.src('src/directives/**/*.js'),
            gulp.src('src/filters/**/*.js'),
            gulp.src('src/components/**/*.js'),
            gulp.src(config.vendors)
        )
        .pipe(plugin.sourcemaps.init())
        // .pipe(plugin.angularFilesort())
        .pipe(plugin.concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(gulpif(global.isProd, plugin.uglify()))
        .pipe(plugin.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(global.isProd ? config.scripts.dest : config.scripts.temp))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Build: Vendors
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('build:vendors', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.vendors)
        .pipe(plugin.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(plugin.concat('vendors.js'))
        .pipe(gulpif(global.isProd, plugin.uglify()))
        .pipe(plugin.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(global.isProd ? config.scripts.dest : config.scripts.temp));
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Build: HTML
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('build:html', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.templates.files)
        .pipe(gulpif(global.isProd, plugin.htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true, minifyCSS: true})))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(global.isProd ? config.buildDir : config.tempDir))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Build: Templates
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('build:templates', function() {
    var options = {
        filename: 'templates.js',
        module: 'carrentalz'
    };

    return gulp.src(config.templates.src)
        .pipe(plugin.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(templateCache(options))
        .pipe(plugin.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(global.isProd ? config.templates.dest : config.templates.temp))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Build: GZip
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('build:gzip', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.gzip.src)
        .pipe(plugin.gzip(config.gzip.options))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.gzip.dest));
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Inject
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('inject', function () {
    var config = {
        exclude: [
            'bower_components/SHA-1/sha1.js',
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
        ]
    };

    var scripts = gulp.src([
        '!./src/**/*.template.js',
        '!./**/LOADING-LOCADORAS.hyperesources',
        '!./src/**/*Component.js',
        'src/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(plugin.angularFilesort());

    var options = {
        transform: function (filePath) {
            filePath = filePath.replace('/src', '');
            return '<script src="' + filePath + '"></script>';
        }
    };

    return gulp.src('src/index.html', { base: './' })
        .pipe(wiredep(config))
        .pipe(plugin.inject(scripts, options))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Serve
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('serve', function () {
    browserSync.use(
        spa({
            selector: '[carrentalz]',
            history: {
                index: '/index.html'
            }
        })
    );

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: global.isProd ? config.buildDir : config.tempDir,
            port: config.browserPort,
            ui: {
                port: config.UIPort
            },
            ghostMode: false,
            open: false
        }
    });

    gulp.watch(config.styles.files, ['compile:sass']);
    gulp.watch(config.scripts.files, ['build:scripts']);
    gulp.watch(config.templates.files, ['build:html']);
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Serve: Dev
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('serve:dev', function(cb) {
    global.isProd = false;
    runSequence('build:dev', 'serve', cb);
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Serve: Prod
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('serve:prod', function(cb) {
    global.isProd = true;
    runSequence('build:prod', 'serve', cb);
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Build: Dev
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('build:dev', function(cb) {
    global.isProd = false;
    runSequence('del', ['build:html', 'compile:sass', 'build:styles', 'build:images', 'build:favicons', 'build:scripts', 'loadingWA', 'build:fonts'], cb);
});

// -------------------------------------
//   Task: Build: Prod
// -------------------------------------

gulp.task('build:prod', function(cb) {
    global.isProd = true;
    // runSequence('del', ['build:html', 'compile:sass', 'build:styles', 'build:images', 'build:favicons', 'build:vendors', 'build:scripts', 'build:templates', 'build:fonts'], 'build:gzip');
    runSequence('del', ['build:html', 'compile:sass', 'build:styles', 'build:images', 'build:favicons', 'build:vendors', 'build:scripts', 'loadingWA', 'build:fonts'], cb);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve:dev']);
```

FooterController:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('carrentalz').controller('footerController', footerController);

    footerController.$inject = ['LocadoraService', 'toastr', '$window'];

    function footerController(LocadoraService, toastr, $window) {
        var $ctrl = this;

        $ctrl.loading = false;
        $ctrl.cadastrarLocadora = _cadastrarLocadora;
        $ctrl.openModal = _openModal;
        $ctrl.closeModal = _closeModal;
        $ctrl.open = {};
        $ctrl.busca = '';
        $ctrl.questoes = [];
        $ctrl.errorEmail = '';

        function _openModal(param){
            if (param === 'modalTelefone') {
                $ctrl.abrirModal =  true;
            } else {
                $ctrl.open[param] = true;
            }

            angular.element('body').addClass('modal-open');
            //param === 'modalTelefone' ? $ctrl.abrirModal =  true : $ctrl.open[param] = true;
            $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }

        function _closeModal (param) {
            angular.element('body').removeClass('modal-open');
            $ctrl.open[param] = false;
        }

        function _cadastrarLocadora() {

            if (!$ctrl.emailLocadora) {
                angular.element('.form-control.newsletter.lg')[0].focus();
                $ctrl.errorEmail = 'Campo Email obrigatório.';
                return;
            }

            $ctrl.loading = true;

            LocadoraService.cadastrarLocadora($ctrl.emailLocadora)
                .then(function(resultado) {
                    toastr.success('Cadastro efetuado, obrigado.');
                    $ctrl.emailLocadora = '';
                }, function(error) {
                    console.error('Problemas ao efetuar cadastro. Tente novamente.');
                }).finally(function(){
                    $ctrl.loading = false;
                    $ctrl.errorEmail = '';
                });
        }
    }
})();
```

And index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>CarRentalz</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="assets/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="assets/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="assets/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="assets/favicons/manifest.json">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="assets/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#660099">

    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <!-- android -->
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <!-- iOS -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="translucent-black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Carrentalz">
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-cloak ng-app="carrentalz" class="-carrentalz" ng-strict-di>
    <div class="appCarrentalz">
        <div id="spinner-content" us-spinner spinner-key="spinner-content"></div>
        <div ui-view="conteudo" class=""></div>
        <ng-include class="print-footer" src="'partials/footer/footer.html'"></ng-include>

        <div class="modal__footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Anyone knows what can be wrong?

Best regards.

Comment: You're the only person who's able to figure this out, the question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's even not clear where this 'FooterController' is supposed to be included. This error means that either the file wasn't included to the bundle, or `carrentalz` module was overridden at some point (like in this case https://stackoverflow.com/a/44231511/3731501 ), or `carrentalz` module isn't used in the app at all.

Comment: if I put the bundle here, is it better? But I already searched here and I didn't find any case with `.module('carrentalz', [])` twice.

Comment: It's not `.module('carrentalz', [])` but `.module('carrentalz', [...])`. You should search for `module('carrentalz',` string. Any way, these are the only options that cause this error here. A link to bundle file will help. Consider also providing a repo that can replicate this build and problem.